# Animate height of element based on content inside in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to animate the height shrinking and growing based on content inside of the element using ng-if.  The issue here is with nganimate I can't get the animation to work at all.  It's a simple example.

```
<div>
     <div ng-if="this">
         Small text
     </div>
     <div ng-if="that">
          <p>Reall long text that can</p>
          <p>be several lines long</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` to do that

```
<div>
     <div ng-class="{small: if-Your-condition-True}">
         Small text
     </div>
     <div ng-class="{big: if-Your-condition-True}">
          <p>Reall long text that can</p>
          <p>be several lines long</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

in this method, you can create an animation